# Арифметика указателей Си

Tags: c, указатели

Наткнулся на странный "баг" в программе на Си:

```
//...
#define CAPACITY (1000+1) // ибо N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000)
int *g[CAPACITY]; //g[i][0] is length of g[i].
//g[0][0] the length of g; g[0][i] currently ALLOCATED g[i] size
//...
int main(){
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    g[0] = malloc(sizeof(g[0][0] * CAPACITY));
    g[0][0] = N;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        g[0][i] = 1000; //initial reserved space for each list is 1000
        g[i] = malloc(sizeof(g[i][0]) * g[0][i]);
        g[i][0] = 0; //real curr length of g[i]
    }
    //баг здесь
}
```

Это вообще-то "массив списков переменной длинны" для хранения графа я так сделал. И все было хорошо но вдруг я заметил что `g[1][0]==1000`.
Стал проверять. Если поставить точку останова на "баг здесь",  почему `g[1][0]==1000`?

То есть именно после этой строчки

```
   for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        g[0][i] = 1000; //<-этой при i=20
```

`g[1][0]` становится равно `1000`

Это x64 код и

[image: sizeof int != sizeof int*]

если это важно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g[0] = malloc(sizeof(g[0][0] * CAPACITY));
```

Здесь у вас выделяется память не под столько элементов, сколько Вы ожидаете. Из-за этого происходит запись за пределы массива. Правильный вариант:

```
g[0] = malloc(sizeof(g[0][0]) * CAPACITY);
```

Comment: А ой, опять невнимательность. Извиняюсь. Спасибо( Правильно не давали задать вопрос мне)